# calculating the volume of a set

Tags: diffeomorphism, fubini-tonelli-theorems

How can I calculate $\int_M1dV$ for $M:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4, x^2+y^2\geq 1\}$ ? I think I need a diffeomorphism to calculate this integral. What diffeomorphism should I use?

Comment: Hint: Use a spherical coordinate system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with cylinders in spherical coordinate system is not very convenient, so I will stick to the cylindrical coordinates. Note that in the cylindrical coordinate $(r,\theta,z)$, your first constraint says
$$r^2 \le 4 - z^2 \iff r \le \sqrt{4-z^2}$$
and the second constraint says $r^2 \ge 1 \iff r > 1$ (since $r>0$ is dictated by the coordinates themselves).

So it sounds like your volume is just
$$
V = \int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta = 2\pi}
    \int_{z = -2}^{z=2}
    \int_{r = 1}^{r=\sqrt{4-z^2}} r drdzd\theta
$$
by symmetry in $z$...

Comment: $z = x^2 + y^2$ is a paraboloid.

Comment: When you are using cylindrical coordinates, isn't there an $r$ as the Jacobian missing in your calculation?

Comment: @Lukas +1, fixed, thanks

Comment: @on1921379 not sure where does this enter into play? First constraint is a sphere, the second is a cylinder...

Comment: @gt6989b That's right, my mistake. Thanks.